# Public transportation from the Ft. Lauderdale airport to the Miami airport

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, fll, mia

Is there public transportation from Ft. Lauderdale-Hollywood International Airport (FLL) to Miami International Airport? I would like to take Southwest Airlines from Tampa to Miami — the price is great! — but need to fly to Europe out of Miami. Would Uber be doable?

Comment: Depends on the time of day, but [Tri-Rail between Palm Beach, Ft Lauderdale and Miami airport](http://www.tri-rail.com/) looks a possible option

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do this, you are arranging your own connection and are responsible for anything that goes wrong. If your Southwest flight is delayed or cancelled (or you get stuck in traffic or on a broken train or anything when transferring between airports) and you no-show for the flight to Europe, the airline has no obligation to do anything for you.

Answer (score 8):

There is public transportation from FLL to MIA using the combination of Tri-Rail and the FLL-TriRail Shuttle.  The FLL TriRail Station is the Dania Beach Station across I-95.  The Shuttle is timed to meet the train and is not continuous.  The MIA TriRail station is essentially at the airport.

Details here: http://www.tri-rail.com/airport-connections/

Uber/Lyft would be about $40 from FLL to MIA.  There is also a van/limo service that offers a flat rate FLL-MIA of $35, I think, it's been 3 years since I've used it.

Depending on the time of your flight and how many hours you have, you can take Amtrak to the Miami Station, ~$40.  From there, an Uber would be about $10.